# How to run the Linux commands which is saved in a text file from python script?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Suppose I have a file 'commands.txt' which has list of linux commands line-by-line (for example: who, pwd, ls, ps, clear etc.,)

I need a python script wherein when run should execute all the linux commands one-by-one in the console/shell.

I am looking for different approaches to do it.

May be one approach I can think off is using os module in Python. (Please correct me if I missed out anything here)

```
import os

with open("commands.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        os.system(line)
```

Kindly help me with different approaches to this problem.

-TIA

Comment: `os.system("sh commands.txt")` ?

Comment: that would work, but what if one command is a `cd`, and one is `export X=Y`. That would NOT work. Why not running a bash on your `commands.txt` file instead?

Comment: create a bash script (.sh) with correct shebang (#!/usr/bin/env bash), make it +x then, os.system("./myscript.sh")

Comment: There sure seems to be more to this question than is being asked, as a shell script would be easier. Why are you trying to execute these commands in python instead of as a shell script? Why can't you just use the "commands.txt" file as a shell script and call via os.system()? What is the context surrounding this, and what requirements do you have that are not yet met?

Answer (score 0):

Like @papey said,

1. Create a bash script (.sh) file, with the correct shabang (#!/usr/bin/env bash).
2. You could write in your Python script the following then:

   `import os`

   `os.system("chmod +x myscript.sh")`

   `os.system("./myscript.sh")`